# Using python requests over HTTPS seems to corrupt the payload

Tags: python, python-3.x, rest, https, python-requests

I have built a web server in C++ for a school project. I decided to use Python3 and `request` to build automated testing for the Restful API. However, I am having an issue where my request body isn't properly decoded by the server when sent over HTTPS, with `requests`.

here is the expected response, with requests, over http:

```
>>> resp = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:8080/usager/identification", verify=False, json={"ip": "12.2.2.2", "mac":"FF:11:11:DD:DD:DD", "nom": "test_user1"}) ; resp.content
b'{"identificateur":4139190850,"message":"connection successful"}'
```

but over https, I get a 'malformed request', meaning the server didn't find the fields `ip`, `mac` and `nom` in the payload:

```
>>> resp = requests.post("https://127.0.0.1:4433/usager/identification", verify=False, json={"ip": "12.2.2.2", "mac":"FF:11:11:DD:DD:DD", "nom": "test_user1"}) ; resp.content
/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:847: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning)
b'Malformed request'
```

Oddly enough, it works with curl, over HTTPS:

```
curl -k -X POST https://127.0.0.1:4433/usager/identification --data '{"ip": "12.2.2.2", "mac":"FF:11:11:DD:DD:DD", "nom": "test_user1"}' && echo {"identificateur":4139190850,"message":"connection successful"}
```

I also tried using `data` instead of `json` in python, with similar results:

```
>>> resp = requests.post("https://127.0.0.1:4433/usager/identification", verify=False, data='{"ip": "12.2.2.2", "mac":"FF:11:11:DD:DD:DD", "nom": "test_user1"}') ; resp.content
/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:847: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning)
b'Malformed request'
```

I can't figure out what requests is doing different than curl here. I could always hardcode a curl command in the python code for this test only, but that makes no sense.

Thanks for your time.

Edit:
curl with verbose output:

```
{16:34}~/code/tp/inf3995-01/project/server/src/common/test:f341 ✗ ➭ curl -v -k -X POST https://127.0.0.1:4433/usager/identification --data '{"ip": "12.2.2.2", "mac":"FF:11:11:DD:DD:DD", "nom": "test_user1"}' && echo
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 4433 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, [no content] (0):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, [no content] (0):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, [no content] (0):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, [no content] (0):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, [no content] (0):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=CA; ST=Quebec; O=Caf�-Bistro �l�vation, Inc.; CN=127.0.0.1
*  start date: Nov  8 18:38:05 2018 GMT
*  expire date: Nov  8 18:38:05 2019 GMT
*  issuer: C=CA; ST=Quebec; L=Montreal; O=Team One, Inc.; OU=Server Dept.
*  SSL certificate verify result: unable to get local issuer certificate (20), continuing anyway.
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS app data, [no content] (0):
> POST /usager/identification HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1:4433
> User-Agent: curl/7.62.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 66
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> 
* upload completely sent off: 66 out of 66 bytes
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, [no content] (0):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, [no content] (0):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS app data, [no content] (0):
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Connection: Keep-Alive
< Content-Length: 63
< 
* Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact
{"identificateur":4139190850,"message":"connection successful"}
```

EDIT 2: I gathered more informations using gdb on the server and Wireshark:

body of the request, on server side, using `curl`:

curl request:

```
curl -k -X POST https://127.0.0.1:4433/usager/identification --data '{"ip": "12.2.2.2", "mac":"FF:11:11:DD:DD:DD", "nom": "test_user1"}' && echo
```

data on server side:

```
(gdb) p body
$29 = "{\"ip\": \"12.2.2.2\", \"mac\":\"FF:11:11:DD:DD:DD\", \"nom\": \"test_user1\"}"
```

And with request:

request:

```
>>> headers = {'Connection': 'Keep-Alive', 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
>>> data = '{"ip": "12.2.2.2", "mac":"FF:11:11:DD:DD:DD", "nom": "tesr1"}'
>>> response = requests.post("https://127.0.0.1:4433/usager/identification", verify=False, headers=headers, data=data) ; response.text
```

body on server side:

```
(gdb) p body
$31 = "\000{\"ip\": \"12.2.2.2\", \"mac\":\"FF:11:11:DD:DD:DD\", \"nom\": \"tesr1\""
```

So using the same data in request results in a corruption of the data: a null terminator is added to the beginning and the closing brace is removed.

Comment: Can you provide `curl` verbose output? It may help identifying the issue.

Comment: The curl finds an expired certificate I set up some time ago, I'm not sure it's relevant

Comment: Did you try to specify certificate in you Python, because their request should be same before encrypted.

Comment: Could you turn on verbose logging for requests as well? http://docs.python-requests.org/en/v0.10.6/user/advanced/#verbose-logging

Comment: Read the whole [InsecureRequestWarning](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings) go to the link and follow the guid.

Comment: @stovfl I am aware there is a warning but it's not relevant here